# How to modify angular-material2 mat-checkbox left icon size and color?

Tags: angular-material2

angular material2 mat-checkbox

How do I modify the left icon size, and the left icon state color?

```
<mat-checkbox>Like Me.</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: For state color, use the `[color]` input. For sizing, please see below.

Answer (score 19):

You can use this ( **.mat-checkbox-inner-container**  ) CSS class to modify the `mat-checkbox`

```
.mat-checkbox-inner-container {
  height: 50px!important;
  width: 50px!important;
}
```

> **Note** that you need to put the style modification in styles.css root folder (
>   /src/styles.css ) and not in the components css.
>
> Also put **!important** ( width: 50px!important; ) to override the
>   default style.

Below is the default style for the mat-checkbox

```
.mat-checkbox-inner-container {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 8px;
    order: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you a _have_ to use this in the main css?

Comment: @Cammy In that way we can be able to override the style of the checkbox.

Comment: @Cammy Research "View Encapsulation" for clarity

Answer (score 14):

If you want to change color then use these in your CSS file

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: black;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
     stroke: #000 !important;
   }
```

**Hope this css will resolve your issue**

Comment: You can add your color for stroke property, its working for me!!

Answer (score 2):

to change styles use classes and define them in your scss component file.

When you see that this not work's, use the selectors :host /deep/ before the class name in each of the scss defined classes.

The size of the icons is defined by the font-size not width / height

Hope I helped you

Comment: this could work
but note that using :host /deep/ is deprecated.
for more info please read this link . https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

In my project, we overrode sizes of checkboxes and radio buttons to `16px` in this way:

```css
body .mat-checkbox-inner-container, body .mat-radio-container, body .mat-radio-outer-circle, body .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}

body .mat-checkbox-ripple, body .mat-radio-ripple {
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```